# How do I escape a newline in macro quasiquotes

Tags: scala, macros, scala-quasiquotes

For example:

```
q"import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer\ndef foo: Buffer[Int] = ???"
```

This gives an error, because the newline characters is not resolved.

Comment: Triple quotes and really break the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample from my tmp dir:

```
    evals += q"""assert ($x.productArity >= ${args.length - 1},
    "Bad product arity ("+ $x.productArity +") for assignment")"""
```

Or, just use a semi:

```
q"import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer; def foo: Buffer[Int] = ???"
```

You can't splice something that is parsed away.